# How to DEFINITELY stop Node

Tags: ram, 19.10, nodejs, memory-usage

I am running out of memory on my computer and this is the output of "top":

[image]

Node is taking all my memory.

So I tried the following command several times:

```
sudo pkill -f node
```

Nothing change, when I try to stop it by the ID, it says that the ID doesn't exist, in deed the ID is changing every second. I don't know what is running in the background and I don't know how to stop it. Do you have an idea?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The problem has been solved! Thanks to Terrance! I needed to run "top -c" to see what precise process caused the problem, it was "wekan" so I stopped the process: "systemctl stop snap.wekan.wekan"

Comment: Also, the `-f` option to `pkill` is documented as `The pattern is normally only matched against the process name.  When -f is set, the full command line is used.` RTFM.

Comment: The command to kill a process using `pkill` is only `sudo pkill node`.  There is no reason to specify the `-f` as it thinks that is the full command and so it won't match what is running.  Running `top -c` will show the full commands then you can use `pkill -f /full/command/name` to kill exactly the one you want.

Comment: how about killall -9 node

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo kill -9 30813
```

where `30813` is the process ID (PID) from your screenshot.

Note that it's probably not really "node" per se that you want to stop, but a node application that you are running.

Comment: Nope! As I said the ID is changing every second, so I can't.